# Handle Actions with Controllers - Defaults not displaying

Tags: lightning-aura-components, trailhead

I am currently completing the 'Handle Actions with Controllers' Trailhead course.

I have been able to pass the module but what I cannot do is actually make the values display when I Preview the App.

CMP:

```
<aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" required="true" default="{'sObjectType':'Camping_Item__c',
                                                            'Name':'Item1',
                                                            'Quantity__c':10,
                                                            'Price__c':100,
                                                            'Packed__c':false}"/>

<p>Name_ui:<ui:outputText value="{!v.item.Name}" /></p>

<p>Name: {!v.item.Name}</p>

<p>Price: <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Price__c}" style="currency"/></p>

<p>Quantity: <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Quantity__c}" maximumFractionDigits="2"/></p>

<p>

    <lightning:input type="toggle"

                     label="Packed?"

                     name="isPacked"

                     checked="{!v.item.Packed__c}" />

</p>

<p><lightning:button label="Packed!"

                     name="packed"

                     onclick="{!c.packItem}"/>

</p>
```

Controller.js
({

```
packItem: function(component, event, helper) {

    var a = component.get("v.item");
    a.Name = 'Item2';
    a.Quantity__c = 20;
    a.Price__c = 200;
    a.Packed__c = true;
    component.set("v.item",a);

    // Disable the button

    var btn= event.getSource();
    var BtnMessage =btn.get("v.label");
    component.set("v.item",BtnMessage);
    var btnClicked = event.getSource();
    btnClicked.set("v.disabled",true);
}
```

})

App:

I just get the following error:
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:campingListItem$controller$packItem [Cannot set property 'Name' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {c:campingListItem$controller$packItem}

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Garth

Comment: I just copy your code and test in my org, it's works fine for me. Please make sure you create the Camping_Item__c object with their respective fields.

Comment: When I click preview, this is all that I see:Name_ui:
Name:
Price:
Quantity:
Packed?ActiveInactive
Packed!
Did you have the variable showing when you Previewed via an app?

From what I can see, the custom object Camping_Item__c is setup correctly.

Comment: I have got the initial default values to populate now but updating the app, but when I click the button, the only action that works is the button disabling. How do I get the other variables to update to what is listed here?
App:
<aura:application >
 <c:campingListItem/>
</aura:application>

Such as
a.Name = 'Item2';
a.Quantity__c = 20;
a.Price__c = 200;
a.Packed__c = true;
component.set("v.item",a);